# NetSuite - Sales Order Item Fulfillment script not working

Tags: scripting, netsuite, suitescript2.0, restlet-2.0, netsuite-rest-api

I'm using Restlet scripts and I need to fulfill a Sales Order with a script. I've done it with netsuite-php library but now I need it with NetSuite script
This is my script:

```
    function createItemFulfillmentFromSalesOrder(wcOrderId, serialNumbers) {
            var salesOrder = record.load({
                type: record.Type.SALES_ORDER,
                id: wcOrderId,
                isDynamic: true
            });
            var itemCount = salesOrder.getLineCount({ sublistId: 'item' });

            for (var i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
                var inventoryDetailId = salesOrder.getSublistValue({
                    sublistId: 'item',
                    fieldId: 'inventorydetail',
                    line: i
                });

                if (!inventoryDetailId) {
                    var inventoryDetail = record.create({
                        type: record.Type.INVENTORY_DETAIL,
                        //isDynamic: true
                    });

                    inventoryDetail.setValue({
                        fieldId: 'item',
                        value: salesOrder.getSublistValue({
                            sublistId: 'item',
                            fieldId: 'item',
                            line: i
                        })
                    });
                    inventoryDetail.selectNewLine({ sublistId: 'inventoryassignment' });
                    inventoryDetail.setCurrentSublistValue({
                        sublistId: 'inventoryassignment',
                        fieldId: 'quantity',
                        value: 1
                    });

                    inventoryDetail.setCurrentSublistValue({
                        sublistId: 'inventoryassignment',
                        fieldId: 'issueinventorynumber',
                        value: serialNumbers[i]
                    });

                    inventoryDetail.commitLine({ sublistId: 'inventoryassignment' });

                    inventoryDetailId = inventoryDetail.save();
                }

                var inventoryAssignmentList = [{ issueInventoryNumber: inventoryDetailId }];
                var itemFulfillment = record.transform({
                    fromType: record.Type.SALES_ORDER,
                    fromId: wcOrderId,
                    toType: record.Type.ITEM_FULFILLMENT,
                    isDynamic: true
                });
                itemFulfillment.selectLine({ line: i });
                itemFulfillment.setCurrentSublistValue({
                    sublistId: 'item',
                    fieldId: 'inventorydetail',
                    value: inventoryAssignmentList
                });

                itemFulfillment.commitLine({ sublistId: 'item' });
            }

            var fulfillmentId = itemFulfillment.save();
            return {
                success: true,
                fulfillmentId: fulfillmentId
            };
    }
});
```

But I have this error:
`You have entered an Invalid Field Value <my_inventory_number_internal_id> for the following field: issueinventorynumber`

I've changed the functions and remove the isDynamic parameter but none of this worked. I've tried with different inventory numbers.

Answer (score 0):

What's the value of serialNumbers here?

```
            inventoryDetail.setCurrentSublistValue({
                sublistId: 'inventoryassignment',
                fieldId: 'issueinventorynumber',
                value: serialNumbers[i]
            });
```

If you manage to get the internal ID, try to manually input/test it first via the UI to see if it errors out using that internal ID

When you work with a record in dynamic mode, the order in which you set field values matters